# Why ASCII characters printed in console when run my TestNgbased scripts run in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng, ascii

I recently started using IntelliJ to run my TestNg-Selenium based automation scripts. Everything is as expected except one thing. When I start running my scripts, at start it takes a lot of time printing some weird ASCII characters in the console as shown below:

```
DEBUG [TestNG-test=AG-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire  - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xffffffb3]w[0xffffffb6][0xfffffff7][0x4]Z[0xffffffcf][0x3];*[0xffffffb2][0xffffffff]a[0xffffffb7][0xffffffd8]{9[0xfffffffb];[0xffffffae][0xffffffb3]7T[0xffffffdc][0x1b][0xffffffee]v[0x1e][0xffffffef][0x1d][0xffffff81][0xffffffa8][0xffffffbe][0xffffffc0][0xffffffbb][0xffffffd7]{[0xffffffd4][0xfffffffb][0xffffff94]vo[0xfffffff2][0xffffffa9][0xffffffac][0x7][0xffffffed]@[0xffffffde][0xffffffe1][0xfffffff3][0x10]y[0xffffffab][0xffffffc1][0xffffff9b][0xffffffc2][0xffffff85][0xffffff9d][0xffffff85][0xffffffd7][0xffffff84][0xfffffff5][0xffffff82][0x8][0xffffffee]4S[0xffffffcc][0x11][0xffffff97][0xffffffb1]li-[0xffffffeb][0xffffffd6][0xffffffff]B[0xffffffdc][0x5]1[0xffffffa6]N[0xfffffff9][0xffffffb7][0xffffffb2][0xffffffa7][0xffffffea][0xffffffa8]I[0xffffffea][0x1c]5I[0xffffff9b][0x1]e][0xffffffa4]=[0xe][0xc]}K[0xfffffffb]Y[0xffffffbb][0xe][0x1c][0xffffffe5][0x3]w[0xffffff82][0xfffffff7][0xffffffba][0xffffffc7][0xfffffff6]6%[0xffffffa6]2.[0xffffffb5]=[0x7f]1"
```

100s of lines like above in the console. Its not observed in Eclipse or on my co-worker machines as well. I'm not sure what's wrong. I would appreciate if someone can help.

This is part of our test automation framework having many other jars for REST, SOAP, WebUI and mobile automation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have DEBUG logging enabled and are getting DEBUG messages from the Apache HTTP client. It's not ASCII, it's raw bytes.

Try turning down the log level or filtering it by class. How depends on which logging framework you are using.

Comment: I use Log4J api

Comment: @amit did you have luck filtering your logs to omit these debug messages?